# Cannot get updated list between threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing some courses on MultiThreading in Java. I've tried (following instructor) to synchronise two consumers reading from ArrayList with one producer filling it with some basic input. Yet producer gives first number and consumer gets in infinite loop because it gets empty List. No idea how to force it to get proper values.

Producer:

```
    class MyProducer implements Runnable {
      private List<String> buffer;
      private String color;

    public MyProducer(List<String> buffer, String color) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] nums = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

        for(String num: nums) {
            try {
                System.out.println(color + "Adding..." + num);
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    buffer.add(num);
                    System.out.println(buffer);
                }

                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Producer was interrupted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(color + "Adding EOF and exiting...");
        synchronized (buffer) {
            buffer.add(EOF);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
    class MyConsumer implements Runnable {
      private List<String> buffer;
      private String color;

    public MyConsumer(List<String> buffer, String color) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (buffer) {
            while(true) {
                if (buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Przejście między warunkami działa");
                if (buffer.get(0).equals(EOF)) {
                    System.out.println(color + "Exiting");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(color + "Removed" + buffer.remove(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.siecz-k-.Main.EOF;

public class Main {
    public static final String EOF = "EOF";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
        MyProducer producer = new MyProducer(buffer, ThreadColor.ANSI_CYAN);
        MyConsumer consumer1 = new MyConsumer(buffer, ThreadColor.ANSI_PURPLE);
        MyConsumer consumer2 = new MyConsumer(buffer, ThreadColor.ANSI_RED);

        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer1).start();
        new Thread(consumer2).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to sleep the consumer thread when the buffer is empty.  Right now, if the buffer is empty, your consumer method goes into an infinite loop.